# How to stop renaming a file which was already renamed using loop in shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a directory name `dir1` containing another directories named 1,2,3,4,5. Now I want to rename directory 1 with 4, 2 => 5, 3 => 6, 4 => 5. but my problem is using `mv` command in shell script successfully renamed directory 1,2,3 but in case of 4 which is renamed directory of 1 is replaced with 5. How do i rename those file in loop so that previously renamed file does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing here is kind of peculiar. The resulting names would be:

```
5 (was: 1)
6 (was: 3)
```

The first operation (mv 1 4) would have removed the original "4" directory and replaced it with one. There's a couple of ways to work around this, and two that I can think of off the top of my head would be:

- Renaming all the directories to something with a suffix (e.g. .old) and then renaming each of those directories to their desired names, or
- Simply doing the last operation (mv 4 5) before the first one.

For the first option, you could do it like so:

```
for file in 1 2 3 4; do mv $file $file.old; done
mv 1.old 4
mv 2.old 5 # actually rather redundant since it would be overwritten anyway
mv 3.old 6
mv 4.old 5
```